# StorageException: Permission denied

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

This code comes to catch block, storage permission is given already. I am not getting the issue.

Here is the code -

```
                try {
                boolean created = outputFile.createNewFile();
//Convert bitmap to byte array
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
                byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
//write the bytes in file
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
                fos.write(bitmapdata);
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

and here is the exception

```
2020-02-29 15:46:38.238 25650-25650/com.startech.kiva E/StorageException: Permission denied
    java.io.IOException: Permission denied
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:317)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1008)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.processResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.0:136)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.0:227)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.0:1072)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$12.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)

2020-02-29 15:46:38.238 25650-25650/com.startech.kiva E/com.ks.wallz.helpers.FirebaseDownloadHelper$1: An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
```

**Update** just checked my Android 10 has this issue, my other android 8 does not have this issue.

Comment: Post relevant code that causes the exception as well.

Comment: @khemraj did you seen this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59494844/download-from-firebase-storage-contentresolver-api-29 &  https://helpx.adobe.com/in/experience-manager/kb/permission_denied_error_from_java_io_file.html

Comment: can you try adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` ?

Comment: please check updated question

Comment: @InsaneCat I'm checking them

Comment: did you give permissions in firebase console?

Comment: On which Android version are you testing? @Khemraj

Comment: @WahdatKashmiri yes, permission is given and it is working in other device

Comment: @NIKHILAGGARWAL I am testing on android 10, please check question update last part

Comment: @Khemraj Added an answer for your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line to your Manifest under application tag and it should work -
`android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

Answer (score 0):

Add this code your Manifest permission.

```
<uses-permission
 android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
 android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```

Comment: i think i help you

Comment: Did you seen his question properly "storage permission is given already."

Comment: Storage permission is given in mobile too